# Enabling mobile data connectivity fails on permission revoke

Tags: android

I need to open android device's data connection in my app. My phone is rooted, and its system is android 2.3.5. Unfortunately, the following fails:

```
// open data connection
Class telephonyManagerClz=TelephonyManager.class;
Method mGetITelephony=telephonyManagerClz
        .getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
mGetITelephony.setAccessible(true);
Object iTelephony = mGetITelephony.invoke(tm);
Method mEnableDataConn=iTelephony.getClass()
        .getDeclaredMethod("enableDataConnectivity");
mEnableDataConn.setAccessible(true);
mEnableDataConn.invoke(iTelephony);
```

This is the exception displayed in logcat:
[image]

It seems that I don't have the MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission, but I've added it into Manifest.xml yet. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` is a reserved permission. You can only use system permissions if your application is signed with the system certificate.

During the installation of your app you should see a warning from the PackageManager that the permission was revoked.

Although I'm not entirely familiar with overriding permission restrictions on rooted devices, if you haven't built your system from source, it's unlikely that you have the certificate and the system will simply continue to revoke your permission. I believe it's simply not possible to sign your app to use it.

Comment: so it is an unreachable goal unless i sign my app with the system certificate?

Comment: You may want to try pushing your app into your device's system apps folder.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the best solution Visit http://my.oschina.net/u/578360/blog/198466